# "In a very simple fashion"

Tags: expressions

I don't know where I've heard such expression. I try to explain (for sales) what our software tool does and I use this sentence: "It helps you to deploy apps in a very simple fashion". And then I describe the steps of how it works.

I googled this expression and I found only one reddit post. Is it a widely used expression in the US? Will native speakers understand me? What about non-native speakers like EU folks, will they? Can I rephrase it as "in the simplest possible fashion"?

Thanks!

Comment: What you have is fine and easily understood. If you claim "simplest", you claim something that is very hard to prove.

Comment: Not that it matters for the purpose of your question, but your question as written is either missing a word ("It helps your [company?]/[team?] to deploy...) or else the "your" should be "you."  (I'd have edited it myself but  I'm not sure which one you meant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common phrase, especially in marketing. The general phrase "In _______ fashion" is a common way of describing many things. One notable standout is using "orderly". For example, "The students lined up in an orderly fashion."

In advertising, simplicity is seen as something to boast about and the above method of phrasing is usually seen as a slick line delivery. These things combine so that now almost every product does something "in a simple fashion".

In answer to your question, the vast majority of English speakers will understand this phrase.

Make sure to note however that "simple" is a very different thing from "simplest possible". There is no reason to over exaggerate something like this and in doing so you would probably be making the statement untrue without gaining any real benefits. People are resistant to exaggeration and would most likely only see the flaws in your claim if you claim too much, especially if it is needless. The "Simple" claim is however a lot less aggressive and people will have a hard time taking issue with it unless your apps are particularly difficult to deploy.

All you really achieve by over selling it is a greater level of scrutiny.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion stems from the word "fashion", which we generally think of in terms of clothing. "Fashion" is one of those English words that has various meanings depending on the context in which it is used. In this case, the word is synonymous with "way" and "manner". Thus, it makes sense to use the following phrase (the phrase you used) when describing something which allows deploying apps in a very easy way/manner:

*"It helps you to deploy apps in a very simple fashion"*...which essentially has the same meaning as *"It helps you to deploy apps in a very simple manner".*

In answer to your second question, you could say "in the simplest possible fashion" if you are implying that the product has competition and is arguably the best out of all the others in the market. So for example:

*Products A, B, and C (your product) allow apps to be deployed. But your product performs this function in the simplest possible fashion".*

EDIT: however, using the phrase "simplest possible fashion" doesn't necessarily indicate that there are multiple *products* that do the same thing. Instead, it could refer to the fact that there are different *methods* available for deploying apps. In that case, "simplest fashion" would imply that your method is the easiest to use.
I hope that's helpful.